# Is this socket listener really processing on a multithreaded level?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

We have an application in production that is supposed to be a multithreaded socket listener.  I am starting to have my doubts because the logs the app generates makes it appear as if it is processing the streams it receives synchronously.  In an effort of trying not to paste a wall of code here, I will supply the first portion of supposedly asynch tcp code:  Is this proper practice?

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Start an Asynchronous Socket to listen for connections. 
        /// </summary>
        public static void StartListening()
        {
            Socket listenerSocket = null;

            try
            {
                var ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
                var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[Socket.OSSupportsIPv6 ? 1 : 0];

                //Create TCP/IP Socket
                listenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                listenerSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
                listenerSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, 1);

                //Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
                //listenerSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, m_client.RemotePort));
                listenerSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ListenerPort"])));
                listenerSocket.Listen(m_maxSocketConnections);

                while (true)
                {
                    //Set the event to nonsignaled state
                    m_pAllDone.Reset();

                    //Start an asynchronous socket 
                    listenerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listenerSocket);

                    //Wait until a connection is made and processed before continuing
                    m_pAllDone.WaitOne();
                }
            }
```

Comment: The while(true) loop looks very much like the example from the [BeginAccept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb431f9.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call is not multithreaded, it is simply asynchronous.  From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb431f9.aspx):

`When your application calls BeginAccept, the system usually uses a separate thread to execute the specified callback method and blocks on EndAccept until a pending connection is retrieved.`

The BeginAccept method creates one other thread that blocks and processes the incoming packets asynchronously.  It does not spawn a NEW thread every time a message comes in.

Comment: Ok, here's an excerpt from those same docs:  ...If you want the original thread to block after you call the BeginAccept method, use WaitHandle.WaitOne....  It appears as if the code is doing that.  Is there a reason as to why we would want this thread to block?

Comment: Calling WaitHandle.WaitOne would cause it to behave exactly like the synchronous call.  That's how you would cause the original calling thread to block until the call is completed.  (I'm trying to find an example...)

Comment: Finally, an example of using the wait handle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx .  In short, it just let's you go on, do a little bit more work, and then wait for the async thread to work.

Comment: Hmmmm.. In our environment, I can't think of a reason as to why we would want to wait on the thread.  All of the processing is handled in that AsyncCallback.  Ideally we want to BeginAccept() instantly a client sends a stream.

Comment: I can't think of one either...  You unfortunately cannot read the same socket from multiple threads- you can only have one thing read from any given port/IP combo.  What you want to do is have a loop simply reading the socket as fast as it can and spawning extra threads to do the actual processing of the data.

Comment: The reason that's in there, probably, is that it's in the example code.

Comment: What you said is exactly what the app is intended to do.  However it seems that if I remove the ManualResetEvent object (that's what type m_pAllDone is) and the calls to .Reset() and .WaitOne()  (as well as .Set() in code not shown), the app logs an error and repeats it at a very fast pace... "An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full".

Comment: Nevertheless, I appreciate your time and as such have marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Socket.BeginAccept` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb431f9.aspx) as "Begins an asynchronous operation to accept an incoming connection attempt.", so this part of the operation (the acceptance of the socket connect request) is asynchronous.  That isn't to say that what you do in `AcceptCallback` is guaranteed to be multithreaded- there are plenty of ways in which you could make that synchronous or even single-threaded, even with async sockets.